# How can I map alphabet as keys and the occurence of the letters as values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary to map the amount of times a letter appears to the letter of the alphabet, however I want to print the entire alphabet in the dictionary even if a letter does not appear in the list of strings. So i want the alphabet letter to be the key and the amount of times the letter occurs as the value.

The following is my code

```
import string 
from collections import Counter

listy = ["hello","there","I","am","a","string"]
letter_count = dict( (key, 0) for key in string.ascii_lowercase )
print(dict_count)
```

My expected output should be

```
{a:2,b:0,c:0,d:0,e:3}
```

and so on until i reach z

I realize the key value should be something else in the list comprehension, but I simply cannot figure out what. I just don't exactly know what i can do to map the amount of times a letter occurs to the correct letter in my dictionary so I just added 0 there. Would using a dictionary comprehension be better? I am new to dictionaries, and dictionary comprehension, but a friend of mine recommended I should learn it since apparently it is a powerful tool to have so any help would be appreciated

Comment: With dictionary comprehension: `{k: "".join(listy).count(k) for k in string.ascii_lowercase}`

Comment: Using a dict comprehension is more common and certainly good thing to have in your tool belt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string
listy = ["hello","there","I","am","a","string"]
concatenated_listy="".join(listy).lower()
letter_count = dict( (key, concatenated_listy.count(key)) for key in string.ascii_lowercase )
letter_count
```

Answer would be

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 3, 'f': 0, 'g': 1, 'h': 2, 'i': 2, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 2, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 2, 's': 1, 't': 2, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
listy = ["hello","there","I","am","a","string"]
dict_count = dict.fromkeys(ascii_lowercase, 0)
for letter in ''.join(listy).lower():
    dict_count[letter] += 1

>>> dict_count

{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 6, 'f': 0, 'g': 1, 'h': 4, 'i': 2, 'j': 0, 
 'k': 0, 'l': 4, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 2, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 1, 't': 3,
 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

You could also use `collectoins.Counter` instead of the for-loop:

```
>>> dict_count = dict.fromkeys(ascii_lowercase, 0)
>>> dict_count.update(Counter(''.join(listy).lower()))
>>> dict_count
{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 3, 'f': 0, 'g': 1, 'h': 2, 'i': 2, 'j': 0,
 'k': 0, 'l': 2, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 2, 's': 1, 't': 2, 
 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

---

**Note:** In this case, most approaches with dictionary comprehension will have poor performance (eg. if you use `str.count`), so if you need to use `dict comprehension` try combining it with `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> alpha_count = Counter(''.join(listy).lower())
>>> dict_count = {alpha: alpha_count.get(alpha, 0) for alpha in ascii_lowercase}
>>> dict_count

{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 6, 'f': 0, 'g': 1, 'h': 4, 'i': 2, 'j': 0, 
 'k': 0, 'l': 4, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 2, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 1, 't': 3,
 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can continue your suggested code with the below to read the letters one by one and add them to a histogram of letters encoded in your Dictionary:

```
import string
letterHist = dict((key, 0) for key in string.ascii_lowercase)
listy = ["hello","there","I","am","a","string"]
for word in listy:
   for letter in word:
      letterHist[letter.lower()] += 1
```

And the above should give you:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 3, 'f': 0, 'g': 1, 'h': 2, 'i': 2, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 2, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 2, 's': 1, 't': 2, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
``
listy = ["hello","there","I","am","a","string"]
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 
dict1 = {}
#Create a dictionary to store the number of occurrences of each of the 26 letters
#each word initially set to 0
for i in alphabet:  
    dict1[i] = 0
for j in listy:   
    for k in j.lower(): # Converted to lowercase
        if k in dict1.keys():
            dict1[k] = dict1.get(k,0)+1
print(dict1)
``
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).